# DataTables moment sort by custom format

Tags: laravel, datatables, momentjs

I am using DataTables and moment and have custom date format on my table. 
How can I sort the column by moment?
Here you can see that sorting does not work correctly updated_at column.
I am using Datatable moment. Update_at format already changed by Carbon on Model.
[image: Here you can see column]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">


<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="tickets-table" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>User name</th>
        <th>Last update</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>saddsfdsafdfsafsa</td>
        <td>Sqe Begush</td>
        <td>1 hour ago</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>testing</td>
        <td>User name</td>
        <td>8 hours ago</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>another</td>
        <td>another user</td>
        <td>4 days ago</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>another testing</td>
        <td>user user</td>
        <td>1 week ago</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>another testingsss</td>
        <td>user user11</td>
        <td>1 year ago</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>another test</td>
        <td>user userqww11</td>
        <td>4 months ago</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //$.fn.dataTable.moment("YYYY/MM/DD");
    $('.table').DataTable();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin of the dates is unclear. If you pass `moment().fromNow()` yourself then just stop doing it when the `display` type is `sort` (see below). If you get already formatted data from a source you can use a library like [**chrono**](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono), which can parse "human dates" into "system dates":

```js
var table = $('#tickets-table').DataTable({
  columnDefs: [
    { targets: 2,
      render: function(data, type) {
        if (type == 'sort') {
          var date = chrono.parseDate(data)
          return new Date(date).valueOf()
        } 
        return data
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

demo with the `<table>` above  -> **http://jsfiddle.net/mw0c3f91/**

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert the column dates to required format and then Sort the table.

moment(col[0]).fromNow();